# htaccess redirecting by query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

i'm having difficulties about .htacces and i hope somebody can help..

i need to make a redirection but cant get the query string value..
(i'm also making a redirection www to now-www)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

and when i making a request to /a/td.htm?td=2

> $_GET['route']

prints

```
a/td
```

i need to get

```
a/td=2
```

unfortunately i couldn't find a way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^td=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.htm$ index.php?route=$1=%1 [L]
```